# Overriding data-ajax="false" from parent container in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using the method noted here in the docs to set `data-ajax="false"` on a parent container for [my site](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) but I do have a few cases where I want the page to load via Ajax.

Is there a way to set the default on the parent container but allow individual links to override that setting? Adding `data-ajax="true"` to the individual links doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

To set default for full page load:

```
 $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
 });
```

To set individual, use data-ajax=true.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow other suggestions didn't work for me. But this one did work. Tested.

This script disables all ajax links in the page jquery mobile - and those that should be ajax ones can be used as the a-link below with data-ajax=true.

```
<head>
<!-- ..... -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
                    // Reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html
                    $.extend($.mobile, {
                        linkBindingEnabled: false,
                        ajaxEnabled: false
                    }); 
         });         
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- ..... -->
</head>
<body>
 <a href="holysmokewheredidtheajaxgo.html" data-ajax=true>Well, I'm still ajax. That's true!</a>
</body>
```